# T-SQL split string by - and space

Tags: t-sql, split, charindex

I'm having difficult time with T-SQL and I was wondering if somebody could me point me to the right track.
I have the following variable called @input

```
    DECLARE @input nvarchar(100);
    SET @input= '27364 - John Smith';
   -- SET @input= '27364 - John Andrew Smith';
```

I need to split this string in 3 parts (ID,Firstname and LastName) or 4 if the string contains a MiddleName. For security reason I cannot use functions.

My aproach was use Substring and Charindex.

```
SET @Id = SUBSTRING(@input, 1, CASE CHARINDEX('-', @input)
                    WHEN 0
                        THEN LEN(@input)
                    ELSE 
                        CHARINDEX('-', @input) - 2
                    END);
        SET @FirstName = SUBSTRING(@input, CASE CHARINDEX(' ', @input)
                    WHEN 0
                        THEN LEN(@input) + 1
                    ELSE 
                        CHARINDEX(' ', @input) + 1
                    END, 1000);
        SET @LastName = SUBSTRING(@input, CASE CHARINDEX(' ', @input)
                    WHEN 0
                        THEN LEN(@input) + 1
                    ELSE 
                        CHARINDEX('0', @input) + 1
                    END, 1000);
Select @PartyCode,@FirstName,@LastName
```

I am stuck because I don't know how to proceed and also the code has to be smart enough to add a fourth split if  Middlename exists.

Any thoughts?

Thanks in advance

Comment: `For security reason I cannot use functions.` what does that mean? `LEN()` and `SUBSTRING` are functions

Comment: My guess is creating functions / changing schema is disabled for Toto07 per security. So creating a function would be a no-go. And CLR is out then too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hopefully this is part of a *normalization project*. This data is breaking 1NF and one really should avoid that...

Try it like this

The advantages

- typesafe values
- ad-hoc SQL
- set based

If you want you might use a `CASE WHEN` to check if the last part is `NULL` and place Part2 into Part3 in this case...

```
DECLARE @input table(teststring nvarchar(100));
INSERT INTO @input VALUES
(N'27364 - John Smith'),(N'27364 - John Andrew Smith');

WITH Splitted AS
(
    SELECT CAST(N'<x>' + REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(teststring,N' - ',N' '),N'&',N'&amp;'),N'<',N'&lt;'),N'>',N'&gt;'),N' ',N'</x><x>') + N'</x>' AS XML) testXML
    FROM @input
)
SELECT testXML.value('/x[1]','int') AS Number
      ,testXML.value('/x[2]','nvarchar(max)') AS Part1 
      ,testXML.value('/x[3]','nvarchar(max)') AS Part2 
      ,testXML.value('/x[4]','nvarchar(max)') AS Part3 
FROM Splitted
```

The result

```
Number  Part1   Part2   Part3
27364   John    Smith   NULL
27364   John    Andrew  Smith
```

Comment: SQL Server 2016 adds the STRING_SPLIT function but again, this shouldn't be used as an excuse to break 1NF

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, in this case the new split function would add some extra work, as it returns the parts as single rows and you'd have to use `PIVOT` and `CAST` to achieve the same. Shredding this via XML allows you to get each part **type safe** and **direct**...

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server 2016 has a new built-in function called STRING_SPLIT()

Assuming creating built-in functions, but CLR functions are not allowed:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.WORD_SPLIT
(   
    @String AS nvarchar(4000)
)
RETURNS TABLE 
AS
RETURN 
(
    WITH Spaces AS
    (
        SELECT Spaced.[value], ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY 1 ORDER BY (SELECT 1)) AS ordinal
        FROM STRING_SPLIT(@String, ' ') AS Spaced
    )
    , Tabs AS
    (
        SELECT Tabbed.[value], ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY 1 ORDER BY s.ordinal, (SELECT 1)) AS ordinal
        FROM Spaces AS s
            CROSS APPLY STRING_SPLIT(s.[value], '   ') AS Tabbed
    )
    , NewLines1 AS
    (
        SELECT NewLined1.[value], ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY 1 ORDER BY t.ordinal, (SELECT 1)) AS ordinal
        FROM Tabs AS t
            CROSS APPLY STRING_SPLIT(t.[value], CHAR(13)) AS NewLined1
    )
    , NewLines2 AS
    (
        SELECT NewLined2.[value], ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY 1 ORDER BY nl1.ordinal, (SELECT 1)) AS ordinal
        FROM NewLines1 AS nl1
            CROSS APPLY STRING_SPLIT(nl1.[value], CHAR(10)) AS NewLined2
    )
    SELECT LTRIM(RTRIM(nl2.[value])) AS [value], ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY 1 ORDER BY nl2.ordinal, (SELECT 1)) AS ordinal
    FROM NewLines2 AS nl2
    WHERE LTRIM(RTRIM(nl2.[value])) <> ''
)
GO
```

Usage:

```
-- Not Normailized
SELECT i.*, split.[value], split.[ordinal]
FROM @input AS i
    CROSS APPLY dbo.WORD_SPLIT(i.teststring) AS split

-- Normalized
;WITH Splitted AS
(
    SELECT split.[value], split.[ordinal]
    FROM @input AS i
        CROSS APPLY dbo.WORD_SPLIT(i.teststring) AS split
)
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT [value], 'part' + CONVERT(nvarchar(20), [ordinal]) AS [parts] FROM Splitted) AS s
    PIVOT (MAX([value]) FOR [parts] IN ([part1], [part2], [part3], [part4])
```

Or assuming that, per-security, you are not allowed to make schema changes:

```
WITH Splitting AS
(
    SELECT teststring AS [value]
    FROM @input
)
WITH Spaces AS
(
    SELECT Spaced.[value], ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY 1 ORDER BY (SELECT 1)) AS ordinal
    FROM Splitting AS sp
        CROSS APPLY STRING_SPLIT(sp.[value], ' ') AS Spaced
)
, Tabs AS
(
    SELECT Tabbed.[value], ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY 1 ORDER BY s.ordinal, (SELECT 1)) AS ordinal
    FROM Spaces AS s
        CROSS APPLY STRING_SPLIT(s.[value], '   ') AS Tabbed
)
, NewLines1 AS
(
    SELECT NewLined1.[value], ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY 1 ORDER BY t.ordinal, (SELECT 1)) AS ordinal
    FROM Tabs AS t
        CROSS APPLY STRING_SPLIT(t.[value], CHAR(13)) AS NewLined1
)
, NewLines2 AS
(
    SELECT NewLined2.[value], ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY 1 ORDER BY nl1.ordinal, (SELECT 1)) AS ordinal
    FROM NewLines1 AS nl1
        CROSS APPLY STRING_SPLIT(nl1.[value], CHAR(10)) AS NewLined2
)
, Splitted AS
(
    SELECT LTRIM(RTRIM(nl2.[value])) AS [teststring], ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY 1 ORDER BY nl2.ordinal, (SELECT 1)) AS ordinal
    FROM NewLines2 AS nl2
    WHERE LTRIM(RTRIM(nl2.[value])) <> ''
)
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT [value], 'part' + CONVERT(nvarchar(20), [ordinal]) AS [parts] FROM Splitted) AS s
    PIVOT (MAX([value]) FOR [parts] IN ([part1], [part2], [part3], [part4])
```

Hopefully helpful!

Comment: I agree that Shnugo answer is better for this pivot scenario. It is good to test alternatives for your situation.